# JobRunr Spring Boot: custom `ApplyStateFilter` in the free version for failed jobs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jobrunr

I have a kotlin spring-boot application with jobrunr `org.jobrunr:jobrunr-spring-boot-2-starter:6.1.1`. I would like to be able to catch cases when scheduled job has failed after all retries. Now, by default, information about such failed jobs is stored in table `jobrunr_jobs`. But for me this is not a suitable option, because I only find out about such jobs when I look at this table myself, and not immediately as soon as it happens.

My custom `ApplyStateFilter`:

```kotlin
@Component
class FailedStateFilter(
    private val alertService: AlertService
) : ApplyStateFilter {

    override fun onStateApplied(job: Job, oldState: JobState, newState: JobState) {
        if (mustBeProcessed(job, newState)) {
            alertService.send(job)
        }
    }

    private fun mustBeProcessed(job: Job, newState: JobState) =
        job.jobName == NOTIFICATION_JOB_NAME && newState is FailedState && newState.mustNotRetry()
}
```

[JobRunr Documentation](https://www.jobrunr.io/en/documentation/pro/job-filters/) says:

> A Job Filter can be used to extend the functionality of JobRunr with
> extra business processes when a job succeeds or fails. They also exist
> in the free version

But I don't understand how can I use my custom `ApplyStateFilter` in the **free** version

Answer (score 0):

Job Filters are not automatically registered when used with Spring integration. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74473937), the author of the library shows a way to configure filters using Fluent Java API.

I found even easier method for registering Spring managed Job Filter beans.
Just inject all the implementations of `JobFilter` and add all of them using `BackgroundJobServer` since it already comes as a Spring managed bean. Here is how I did it in java:

```java
@Configuration
public class JobrunrConfig {

    JobrunrConfig(BackgroundJobServer backgroundJobServer, List<? extends JobFilter> jobFilters) {
        backgroundJobServer.getJobFilters().addAll(jobFilters);
    }

}
```